# Taylor expansion of a logaritmic function

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, approximation

A function is given as

$ln (y) = ln(\alpha)-\frac{\lambda}{\gamma}ln(\delta L^{-\gamma}+(1-\delta)K^{-\gamma})$

I need to find the second order Taylor $ln(y)$ around $\gamma=0$.

How can it be done since putting zero for gamma gives infinity?

Thank you

Comment: How large are L and K, and is $\delta$ small?

Comment: $\alpha>0$, $0<\delta<1$ and $\gamma \geq -1$

Comment: L and K are just some constant

Answer (score 0):

This is my take on
a first-order approximation.
If you want more,
you can extend it
to second order.

For small $g$
(instead of $\gamma$),
$A^{-g}
=e^{-g \ln A}
\sim 1-g \ln A
$.

Therefore,
using $\ln(1-z) \sim -z$
(and $d$ instead of $\delta$),

$\begin{array}\\
\frac1{g}\ln(d L^{-g}+(1-d)K^{-g})
&\sim \frac1{g}\ln(d (1-g\ln L) + (1-d)(1-g \ln K))\\
&= \frac1{g}\ln(d -dg\ln L + (1-d)-(1-d)(g \ln K))\\
&= \frac1{g}\ln(1 -g(d\ln L +(1-d) \ln K))\\
&\sim \frac1{g}(-g(d\ln L +(1-d) \ln K)))\\
&\sim -(d\ln L +(1-d) \ln K)))\\
\end{array}
$

I'll leave it at this.